# Getting a redirect loop accessing a webapp's welcome page

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, redirect-loop

I'm not sure why, but accessing my webapp at http://localhost:8080/MyApp is giving me a redirect loop.

I have no servlets or servlet mappings, and my welcome page is at Tomcat/webapps/MyApp/index.html, which is a simple "hello world" html page.

Any ideas? Why would Tomcat be redirecting? Maybe something is configured wrong in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have indeed no servlets or filters mapped on `/*` or `/`, then this can only happen if the first match as defined in a `<welcome-file>` of webapp's `web.xml` is basically referring to `/`.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I just emptied the web.xml for my webapp and the only welcome files listed in conf/web.xml are index.html, index.htm, index.jsp

Comment: Well, admittedly I also assume that the Tomcat config isn't messed up. Can you please describe in detailed steps how you installed, integrated and configured Eclipse+Tomcat from the zero beginning on? Regardless, you may find [those tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) more than useful to restart freshly with JSP/Servlet/Tomcat/Eclipse.

Comment: I stumbled upon your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4824239) which didn't gave me a good feeling. If you have fiddled something in Tomcat's own `web.xml`, then I strongly recommend to undo that. If in vain, remove Tomcat from Eclipse, remove Tomcat folder and unzip the Tomcat download again for a fresh Tomcat instance and re-integrate it in Eclipse. For Tomcat-in-Eclipse guidelines, I suggest you to take a look [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/01/jsf-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-tomcat.html#IntegrateTomcatInEclipse) (only this chapter, just ignore the rest of the article)

Comment: haha you're on to me! Yea I deleted the server and made a new one... it fixed it. Must've been a config issue... although I'm not sure exactly how I broke it >.<